# file.tell() inconsistency

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, buffering

Does anybody happen to know why when you iterate over a file this way:

### Input:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print "f.tell(): ",f.tell()
```

### Output:

```
f.tell(): 8192
f.tell(): 8192
f.tell(): 8192
f.tell(): 8192
```

I consistently get the wrong file index from tell(), however, if I use readline I get the appropriate index for tell():

### Input:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if (line == ''):
        break
    print "f.tell(): ",f.tell()
```

### Output:

```
f.tell(): 103
f.tell(): 107
f.tell(): 115
f.tell(): 124
```

I'm running python 2.7.1 BTW.

Comment: just covering the required question: are you sure that you have not reached the end of the file in the first example?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using open files as an iterator uses a read-ahead buffer to increase efficiency. As a result, the file pointer advances in large steps across the file as you loop over the lines.

From the [File Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) documentation:

> In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right. However, using `seek()` to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.

If you need to rely on `.tell()`, don't use the file object as an iterator. You can turn `.readline()` into an iterator instead (at the price of some performance loss):

```
for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
    print f.tell()
```

This uses the [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) `sentinel` argument to turn any callable into an iterator.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you know where the file has started from (e.g. from 0 or a previous `seek()`, you can just keep track of the file position manually instead of using `tell()`. Just increment a counter by the length of each line you read from `next()`. Now you have a 'correct' file position and the performance boost from the readahead.

Comment: @TomDalton: You cannot do this on a Windows platform as line separators are translated. Reading a line there gives you x characters for every x + 1 bytes on disk. This also doesn't work when using `io.open()` where multi-byte characters on disk are decoded to one unicode codepoint. Luckily `io.open()` file objects don't need the work-around presented in this answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Shameless self-advertisement: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48055409/2988730. Is this the same reason that `tell` was completely disabled in Py3 on iteration?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: no, the reasons for Python 3 are different; the `TextIO*` wrappers rely on several layers of buffering and supporting tell would have serious performance implications.

Answer (score 12):

The answer lies in the following part of Python 2.7 source code (`fileobject.c`):

```
#define READAHEAD_BUFSIZE 8192

static PyObject *
file_iternext(PyFileObject *f)
{
    PyStringObject* l;

    if (f->f_fp == NULL)
        return err_closed();
    if (!f->readable)
        return err_mode("reading");

    l = readahead_get_line_skip(f, 0, READAHEAD_BUFSIZE);
    if (l == NULL || PyString_GET_SIZE(l) == 0) {
        Py_XDECREF(l);
        return NULL;
    }
    return (PyObject *)l;
}
```

As you can see, `file`'s iterator interface reads the file in blocks of 8KB. This explains why `f.tell()` behaves the way it does.

The documentation [suggests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) it's done for performance reasons (and does not guarantee any particular size of the readahead buffer).

Comment: Do you happen to have a similar insight for Python3? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48055409/2988730

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same read-ahead buffer issue and solved it using [Martijn's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145082/file-tell-inconsistency/14145118#14145118).

I've since generalized my solution for anyone else looking to do such things:

https://github.com/loisaidasam/csv-position-reader

Happy CSV parsing!