# How to detect end of file in Python after iterating the file object with "for" statement

Tags: python

I know to iterate a file line by line, I can use construct like this:

```
for line in file:
    do stuff
```

But if I also have a **break** statement somewhere inside the **for**, once I am out of the **for** block, how do I tell if it is the **break** that take me out of the **for** construct *OR* it is the because I hit the end of file already?

I tried the suggestion from [How to find out whether a file is at its `eof`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140281/how-to-find-out-whether-a-file-is-at-its-eof):

```
f.tell() == os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
```

But that doesn't seem to work on my Windows machine. Basically, f.tell() always returns the size of the file.

Comment: the somewhat-rarely used `for/else`.  Which should have been named `for/nobreak`, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: Iterating over a file causes python to buffer the file in memory which leads to [somewhat unexpected behavior when you call `f.tell()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145082/file-tell-inconsistency)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could use `for..else`

```
for line in f:
  if bar(line):
    break
else:
  # will only be called if for loop terminates (all lines read)
  baz()
```

[source](http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html)

> the else suite is executed after the for, but only if the for
>   terminates normally (not by a break).

[Ned Batchelder's article about for..else](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201110/forelse.html)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this option! One of the things that make python great for scripting

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution is to set a flag:

```
eof = False
for line in file:
    #do stuff
    if something:
        break
else:
    eof = True
```

In the end, if `eof` is `True`, it means you hit the end of the file.  Otherwise, there are still some lines.

What's important here is the `for...else` construct.  The else-block will only be run if the for-loop runs through without hitting a `break`.