# Unexpected file pointer position using ftell() in python traversing through for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Getting unexpected output of the following code below:

`sample.txt` contains:

> this is the first line
>   this is the second line
>   this is the third line
>   this is the fourth line
>   this is the fifth line
>   this is the sixth line

code:

```
import sys  

f1=open("sample3.txt",'r')  

print f1.tell()  

for line in f1:  
    print line  
    print "postion of the file pointer",f1.tell()
```

Output:

```
0  
this is the first line  
postion of the file pointer 141  
this is the second line  
postion of the file pointer 141  
this is the third line  
postion of the file pointer 141  
this is the fourth line  
postion of the file pointer 141  
this is the fifth line  
postion of the file pointer 141  
this is the sixth line  
postion of the file pointer 141
```

I expect something which shows the file pointer position the end of each line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file.tell() inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145082/file-tell-inconsistency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tell()` does not work when you iterate over a file object.
Due to some optimizations for faster reads, the actual current potion in the file does not make sense once you start iterating.

Python 3 provides more help here:

```
OSError: telling position disabled by next() call
```

Using `readline()` works better:

```
from __future__ import print_function

f1 = open('sample3.txt')
line = f1.readline()
while line:
    print(line)
    print("postion of the file pointer", f1.tell() )
    line = f1.readline()
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  Can you please eloborate why can't we iterate the file using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found the relevant part in the documentation:

> A file object is its own iterator, for example iter(f) returns f
>   (unless f is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in
>   a for loop (for example, for line in f: print line.strip()), the
>   next() method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input
>   line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit when the file is open
>   for reading (behavior is undefined when the file is open for writing).
>   In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the
>   lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a
>   hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead
>   buffer, combining next() with other file methods (like readline())
>   does not work right. However, using seek() to reposition the file to
>   an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.